# Evaluate $\int_0^i e^z dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, exponential-function

Evaluate $\int_0^i e^z dz$.

Let $z(t) = it$, where $ 0\leq t \leq 1$.

Then, $\int_0^i e^z \, dz = \int_0^1 ie^{it} dt = e^i - e^0 = e^i - 1 = \cos{1} + i\sin{1}$.

This looks fairly simple, but I just want to make sure that I am doing this correctly.

Comment: Looks absolutely fine.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: You lost the $-1$ at the end, but otherwise, it looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the fact that the anti-derivative of $e^z$ is $e^z$ and that $e^z$ is holomorphic everywhere to get that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^ie^z\,\mathrm{d}z
&=\left.e^z\vphantom{\int}\,\right]_0^i\\
&=e^i-1
\end{align}
$$
independent of the path taken between $0$ and $i$.

However, parametrizing the straight line from $0$ to $i$, as you've done, is fine (once you bring back the lost $-1$).